# Grails render XML lose xml format and tags

Tags: xml, grails

I request Google Places API and would like to get the response in XML.
I do this:

```
def http = new HttpURLClient( )
def resp = http.request(url:uRL)
render(text: resp.getData(), encoding:"UTF-8", contentType:"text/xml")
```

It returns the data, but without the XML tags. So the plain data as string. I am 100% sure, that I get XML formatted data back from Google. The response from Google looks like (this shows the browser):

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<name>Beth-El Synagogue</name>
<vicinity>Elizabeth Av & Downing, St. John's</vicinity>
<type>synagogue</type>
<type>place_of_worship</type>
<type>establishment</type>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>47.5799640</lat>
<lng>-52.7172920</lng>
</location>
</geometry>
<icon>
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_jewish-71.png
</icon>
<reference>
CnRwAAAAH3oJJ3PaJPk5kesLiioompBTCh2NUBDxAh-wUKwZkFeolqoDCOEoOTYe9UpUdhVhkqMoL9mPPd-C0PuIvkyqBwfvdli1zHvaaEfJklQBHd-haHfMceF4vlPxV5r9kaSyWTwOAGSJWQhT6pkXmmoMCBIQbP457ZvQWJsX0JIEc-DnORoU_NRRZIlZN08azb3UL_X-xpqS6N4
</reference>
<id>b61e059f04e643fce7f4750a42c686901096bab3</id>
</result>
<html_attribution>
Listings by <a href="http://www.yellowpages.ca/">YellowPages.ca</a>
</html_attribution>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

I just want to render the response again. So, what is wrong with the code on the top?
Thx.

Comment: have you `println`'d the `resp.getData()` to see if it matches?

Comment: Are you sure that's not just how your browser is rendering the XML response - have a look at "view source" (or whatever it's called in your particular browser).

Comment: if xml is formatted properly, the browser shows it. And the println shows the same output without tags. So basically is the half of the information missing. There are just all the values.

Comment: `render resp.getData() as XML` change something in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Parse XML to text first:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
....
def http = new HttpURLClient( )
def resp = http.request(url:uRL)
def xmlAsText = XmlUtil.serialize(resp.data)
render(text: xmlAsText, encoding:"UTF-8", contentType:"text/xml")
```